# SVG <use> element transition not working

Tags: svg, css-transitions

I'm trying to use CSS transisions with SVG `<use>` element.
The problem is that the transition works with the original element but not inside the  element on adding/removing class through `classList`.

However when I disable the `transform` property in the browser tools, it works.

Can someone help with this?

The small element is the source element which works, The bigger one is using `<use>`

https://codepen.io/karanS/pen/GqVLGv